# Cannot anchor rsync excludes when cloning from root

Tags: rsync, exclude

I'm synchronizing data using

```
rsync [...] --exclude='/var' / host:/
```

When I execute this, part of the output is

```
*deleting   var/log/nginx/https.error.log.1.gz
*deleting   var/log/nginx/https.error.log
```

showing me that the `--exclude='/var'` argument did not match the shown filenames which makes sense because the filenames do not start with a slash. However, I do not want to omit the leading slashes in my expression because I only want to match  the `/var` folder, but not a `/some/where/var` folder. How can I achive this?

**edit:** I was wrong. The above command was a simplified version of my actual command and the problem had nothing to do with the leading slashes. Although the filenames are shown without leading slashes in rsync's output, the pattern-matching works as it should.

Comment: `/var` doesn't match `var/log...`

Comment: @IporSircer This shouldn't matter, as rsync doesn't recurse into excluded directories.